# JMS: Server closed connection and reconnection not permitted

Tags: java, wso2, jms, wso2-message-broker

I want to count the messages in the queue.

```
InitialContext ctx = initQueue();
connFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(CF_NAME);
queueConnection = connFactory.createQueueConnection();
queueConnection.start();
queueSession =
                queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, 
QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup(queueName);

QueueBrowser queueBrowser = queueSession.createBrowser(queue);
```

But here it stops ------->QueueBrowser queueBrowser = queueSession.createBrowser(queue)

The error message is:
    Active session count: 1: org.wso2.andes.AMQDisconnectedException: Server closed connection and reconnection not permitted.
    javax.jms.JMSException: Error registering consumer: org.wso2.andes.AMQException: Woken up due to class javax.jms.JMSException
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQSession$6.execute(AMQSession.java:2143)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQSession$6.execute(AMQSession.java:2086)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.executeRetrySupport(AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.java:323)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection$3.run(AMQConnection.java:655)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.executeRetrySupport(AMQConnection.java:652)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.failover.FailoverRetrySupport.execute(FailoverRetrySupport.java:102)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQSession.createConsumerImpl(AMQSession.java:2084)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQSession.createBrowserConsumer(AMQSession.java:1039)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQQueueBrowser.(AMQQueueBrowser.java:51)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQSession.createBrowser(AMQSession.java:1031)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQSession.createBrowser(AMQSession.java:1018)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQQueueSessionAdaptor.createBrowser(AMQQueueSessionAdaptor.java:87)
        at com.test.vediamo.ConnectionTest.doGet(ConnectionTest.java:96)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)

Comment: I don't know wso2, but is there permissioning involved ? There might be an explicit 'browse' permission that you don't have - otherwise it might just be a bug or missing feature in the API ? your code looks good, I think.

Comment: Good evening and thank you for the answer.
I thought I could be this I enabled all the permissions, but the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please create a queue first and then create the browser as follows?

QueueBrowser browser = queueSession.createBrowser(queueSession.createQueue("test-queue"));