# how to consult the elements of a JMS queue without deleting them

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, wso2-message-broker

Good morning,
I have a queue in a wso2 message broker.
I would like to know if in java there is a way to be able to consult the elements of a queue without deleting them.
I tried to use the QueueBrowser but the application goes me wrong (my question 
--> [JMS: Server closed connection and reconnection not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614585/jms-server-closed-connection-and-reconnection-not-permitted)).
The connection is correct because if I create a consumer it works for me
I wanted to know if you knew another way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It should work and looking at your code in the linked question it seems correct. A very dirty approach is to actually read the messages within a transaction and rollback when done. Transactions are not always supported, though, and regardless reading and rolling back is expensive, so I would only do that as a last resort.